# Sometimes no sound in flash videos after boot?

Tags: kernel, drivers, audio, adobe-flash, alsa

Sometimes after I boot up the machine, I get no sound in flash videos. First I didn't know why it was happening, but as I read a few articles here and there, I found out it was because of my USB webcam (logitech) - ALSA was messing something up and didn't know how to handle sound drivers well (so they say). So one of the suggestions I found was to force the (in my case) `snd_hda_intel` module load before `snd_usb_audio` module during the boot process. I thought it worked, but after a while the same problem appeared again. If I just unplug the webcam from my computer, sound works perfectly on each boot, but I don't want to get down and insart the cam everytime I need it... Anyone have any suggestions what I should try to fix this?

Comment: how do you force the intel module to load before the usb one? also although distro isn't the problem distro might matter because different distro's handle that stuff differently.

Comment: I use Arch and I put snd_hda_intel to be the first one in rc.conf (it's a basic conf file in Arch Linux and one of things you can do with rc.conf is that you can set additional modules to load through that)

Comment: do you use pulseaudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to fix it by creating a `~/.asoundrc` see http://alsa.opensrc.org/.asoundrc

Specifically you want the opposite of the case here: http://alsa.opensrc.org/.asoundrc#Default_PCM_device

so `aplay -L` with out the usb audio in and and `asoundrc` like this might work:

```
pcm.!default front:Intel
```

If your card (Like mine) gets named `Intel` by alsa just putting that in `~/.asoundrc` should work (if you want it to affect stuff that's not run as your UID then put it in `/etc/asound.conf`)

Oh also none of this really applies if you're using pulseaudio... you need to do different stuff in that case.